# Using Google Checkout in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-checkout, android-pay

Ok, my site has 3 check out options - our credit cards processing , PayPal , and Google Checkout, I handle the first two by processing the request then redirecting the user to a Receipt page to display a printable ticket and show details of the transaction.  This seems very hard to implement with Google Check Out.

So I use `Response.Redirect(...)` to redirect the user to the Google CheckOut.  As far as I understand there  is no way to give Google a Redirect URL for successful transactions.  The only way to do it is give Google a URL to send notifications.

So I am going to create an aspx page to listen to notifications from Google, Here this is will be placed in the database.

My problem is..
    How do I implement all this for a smooth user interface?  The user is going to be redirected to Google (I don't know of a way to do `Response.Redirect` in a new tab or window)  so the user is now logging into google , processing transaction, Then they have to on their own go back to my site , log in, then maybe click on a recent purchases link?? Then I can display the receipt.  This doesn't seem right ...  Is there any other way that other people have implemented Google Checkout a little more smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the classic Checkout API is the newer Wallet API:

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/

The entire transaction is in-app which means the customer never leaves your site. The transaction fees are also cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the `continue-shopping-url` parameter, for more info see the html api parameter reference:

[HTML API Parameter Reference](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference#tag_continue-shopping-url)

Answer (score -1):

Just for information of new developers who want to integrate **Google Wallet** "Google wallet is going to be retired March 2, 2015".

They write "This only applies to web developers accepting payments for digital goods on their own websites using the Google Wallet for digital goods API". Visit the following link for further details

https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573?hl=en

Comment: Well, they are closing one smallish part of google wallet, NOT google wallet.  Edit:  I mean the usage of it is small.  I think I saw a website once that let me use google wallet (drugstore.com)... but that was physical goods, which also isn't being closed...